# Faq By Population , Best Way to organise (Java)

Tags: java

I have a problematic , i need to organize my FAQ between different populations

```
Men ---> Young --> Working
               --> Not Working
    ---> Old
Woman --> Young --> Working
                --> Not Working
      --> Old
```

To do that i use a FAQController with different Array

```
String Qmen[] = new String[12];

String Qwomen[] = new String[12];

String QmenOld[] = new String[12];

String QmenYoung[] = new String[12];

String QwomenOld[] = new String[12];

String QwomenYoung[] = new String[12];

String QmenYoungWorking[] = new String[12];

String QmenYoungNotWorking[] = new String[12];

....
```

The Q before is Question
The same array for the Answer for example : AmanYoung[]

After that i populate with Question/Answer like this

```
 Qmen[0] = "How to contact ?";
 Rmen[0] = "Call at number XXXXX";
```

There is very different questions between all this populations and recently two new populations appears , Man -> Young -> Not Working -> Driver/NotDriver

It's to complicated to organise all this question with all this population

Do you have a new way to do that ? Using Api ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: I think you can use `Tree` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First unless you have a special reason to know that there will be 12 and exactly no more that 12 questions I would use a List<> and not Arrays.

Second You are not using any of Object Oriented features of Java.
I would have at the very least (accessors visibility left empty for simplicity):

```
class FaqEntry{
    String question;
    String answer;
    public FaqEntry(String question, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
enum PopulationWithState {
    MenYoungWorking,
    MenYoungNotWorking;
}
```

And then store the questions in something like:

```
Map<PopulationWithState, List<FaqEntry>> faq = new HashMap<>();
//Fetch list of questions for a type. Return a new List if no questions exist
faq.computeIfAbsent(PopulationWithState.MenYoungNotWorking, k-> new LinkedList<>()).add(new FaqEntry("Question here", "Answer here"));
faq.computeIfAbsent(PopulationWithState.MenYoungNotWorking, k-> new LinkedList<>()).add(new FaqEntry("Question 2 here", "Answer 2 here"));

//Fetch a particular list
List<FaqEntry> menYoungNotWorking = faq.computeIfAbsent(PopulationWithState.MenYoungNotWorking, k-> new LinkedList<>());
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer , can you give me an exemple with two question/answer ?

Comment: Added example usage. Do not forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem.